# Locked out of my local site after transfer

Tags: drush

I put an old site on my new machine and got it up and running, except for clean URLs. The login creds in my notes didn't work so (after a few attempts) I used mysql via drush to change the password, no dice. I also checked to be sure I had the correct user1 name and it is. Though all this, the account got blocked because of all the login attempts, which I also tried to remedy via drush, however it alert still says the account is blocked and I still can't login. I don't know where to go from here.... please help.

Comment: Have you tried the drush user-login command?  Usually works nicely.

Comment: Directly go into database and make some changes on `user` and `variables` table manualy

Answer (score 2):

well you can first

```
drush upwd --password="yourNewPassword" UserName
```

to reset your password.

then you would need to remove the attempts so you can try to login again, you need to truncate the table flood.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE flood
```

Comment: In case anyone else ends up here, and is newbier than me... the truncate command is done from the mysql prompt:  
 mysql -u root ...  
USE sitesDatabaseName ... TRUNCATE TABLE flood --  Although I'm not sure this did anything since the response was Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

Comment: Truncating your flood table will clear the number of attempts of log in lock. So if you tried to log in unsuccessfully for more than 5 times you will be locked outside for a significant amount of time even if you enter the right user/password.